# Is it possible to write a table to a file in JSON format in R?

Tags: json, r

I'm making word frequency tables with R and the preferred output format would be a JSON file. sth like 
   {
     "word" : "dog",
     "frequency" : 12
   }
Is there any way to save the table directly into this format? I've been using the write.csv() function and convert the output into JSON but this is very complicated and time consuming.

Comment: You could presumably use the [rjson](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rjson) package.

Comment: install.packages("fortunes");require(fortunes);fortune(which="Evelyn")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
( tbl <- table(round(runif(100, 1, 5))) )

## 1  2  3  4  5 
## 9 24 30 23 14 

library(rjson)
sink("json.txt")
cat(toJSON(tbl))
sink()

file.show("json.txt")
## {"1":9,"2":24,"3":30,"4":23,"5":14}
```

or even better:

```
set.seed(1)
( tab <- table(letters[round(runif(100, 1, 26))]) )

a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
1 2 4 3 2 5 4 3 5 3 9 4 7 2 2 2 5 5 5 6 5 3 7 3 2 1 

sink("lets.txt")
cat(toJSON(tab))
sink()
file.show("lets.txt")
## {"a":1,"b":2,"c":4,"d":3,"e":2,"f":5,"g":4,"h":3,"i":5,"j":3,"k":9,"l":4,"m":7,"n":2,"o":2,"p":2,"q":5,"r":5,"s":5,"t":6,"u":5,"v":3,"w":7,"x":3,"y":2,"z":1}
```

Then validate it with http://www.jsonlint.com/ to get pretty formatting. If you have multidimensional table, you'll have to work it out a bit...

EDIT:

Oh, now I see, you want the dataset characteristics sink-ed to a JSON file. No problem, just give us a sample data, and I'll work on a code a bit. Practically, you need to carry out the data into desirable format, hence convert it to JSON. `list` should suffice. Give me a sec, I'll update my answer.

EDIT #2:
Well, time is relative... it's a common knowledge... Here you go:

```
( dtf <- structure(list(word = structure(1:3, .Label = c("cat", "dog", 
"mouse"), class = "factor"), frequency = c(12, 32, 18)), .Names = c("word", 
"frequency"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame") )

##   word frequency
## 1   cat        12
## 2   dog        32
## 3 mouse        18
```

If `dtf` is a simple data frame, yes, data.frame, if it's not, coerce it! Long story short, you can do:

```
toJSON(as.data.frame(t(dtf)))
## [1] "{\"V1\":{\"word\":\"cat\",\"frequency\":\"12\"},\"V2\":{\"word\":\"dog\",\"frequency\":\"32\"},\"V3\":{\"word\":\"mouse\",\"frequency\":\"18\"}}"
```

I though I'll need some `melt` with this one, but simple `t` did the trick. Now, you only need to deal with column names after transposing the data.frame. `t` coerces data.frames to matrix, so you need to convert it back to data.frame. I used `as.data.frame`, but you can also use `toJSON(data.frame(t(dtf)))` - you'll get *X* instead of *V* as a variable name. Alternatively, you can use regexp to clean the JSON file (if needed), but it's a lousy practice, try to work it out by preparing the data.frame.

I hope this helped a bit...

Answer (score 3):

These days I would typically use the [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) package.

```
library("jsonlite")
toJSON(mydatatable, pretty = TRUE)
```

This turns the data table into a JSON array of key/value pair objects directly.

Answer (score 1):

RJSONIO is a package "that allows conversion to and from data in Javascript object notation (JSON) format". You can use it to export your object as a JSON file.

```
library(RJSONIO)    
writeLines(toJSON(anobject), "afile.JSON")
```

Comment: I would recommend writing some explanation along with the code to help the OP understand the answer better.

Comment: @Joe: you expect a lot. Self-contained code -> details and code. Diffuse question->diffuse answer.

Comment: Not really - just a few words is good (like @cafe876 added, thanks for that!).  Pure code with no comments at all is not as helpful.  It was also an answer three years after the original question, which means I expect a little more from the answer (a bad question from 3 years ago should just be ignored).